# Special characters are being replaced by question marks in C# MVC (only happens in Linux)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I've been looking for solutions for this problem and none of them have worked so far. I have this TempData in my Controller:

```
TempData["error"] = "Correo electrónico o contraseña incorrectos.";
```

But my view renders it as follows:

> Correo electr�nico o contrase�a incorrectos.

This is only happening when I run the app on my Ubuntu distribution, it doesn't happen on Windows. I've been trying all of these solutions but nothing works:

```
- <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
- @Html.Raw(TempData["error"])
- TempData["error"] = ("Correo electrónico o contraseña incorrectos.").ToString(new CultureInfo("es-ES"));
```

Thanks in advance. :(

Comment: When you say you run the app on Ubuntu, do you mean the server, the client, or both? Have you tried different browsers?

Comment: That's the Unicode *Replacement Character* (see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block) ). It generally indicates that the character being output cannot be rendered. It's likely a font issue; that the font being used isn't capable of rendering the character. It might be an encoding issue (but that's unlikely for a web page being displayed in a browser).

Comment: No, it's not a font issue, because I have text directly written in the view, and it displays accents. The problem is occurring when I try to print the TempData["error"] value in the view with Razor.